# R: How to create kernel density with standard deviation in meter

Tags: r, gaussian, standard-deviation, kernel-density

For my research I need to create a kernel density raster around my species occurence points. I want to use the following method: Calculation of the weighted number of species records in a chosen neighbourhood (in my case Chile) for each cell (weighted by a Gaussian kernel with a standard deviation (SD) of 200km).

How can I create a Gaussian kernel with a standard deviation of 200km?

Comment: Take a look at `kde2d()` in the MASS package.

Comment: I  did that already. My code for that is: 
'dens <- kde2d(pres.locs[,1], pres.locs[,2], h = rep(2, 2), n = c(nrow(occur.chile), ncol(occur.chile)))'
But how can the bandwith (h) be translated to meters or kilometers and is kde2d a gaussian kernel density?

Comment: You should probably include the code that you have already tried. And some test data.

Comment: Presumably only you know whether your data is in km. A "normal" kernel, as `?kde2d` describes it, is a Gaussian kernel. If you also look at the actual function with `kde2d`, no parentheses, you'll see how `h` is being used; looks to me as if it is on the same scale as the data.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you with the last part. `h` is on the same scale as the data? My data is a .csv file with longitude and latitude of my species occurence points. How does this reffer to `h`?